# In Flutter - How to pass the image downloaded from the url

Tags: android, flutter, dart, networkimageview, image-file

Through the API I retrieve data of an object - including its url. I show on one screen an image with url (Image.Network()). Now, after clicking on this image on the list, I want to move to a single image view - how do I pass the image, not the url, to a new view so that the application doesn't have to download it from the url again?

Comment: Can you please show some code of what you have right now? It will be easier to provide an answer

Comment: Either you can pass the image as a parameter, or use `https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image` it will cache the image locally so that it won't download next time.

Comment: my code is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the **image** to **Other Class** like this

```
Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherClass(data: image)));
```

and in **Other class** receive the **image** like

```
   var data;

   OtherClass({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: And how to get the date: image if I only have Object.url (image address)

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen(url: users[index].url);
        }));
    },
[...]
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    final String url;

    DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.url})
        : assert(url != null),
            super(key: key);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: GestureDetector(
                child: Center(
                    child: PhotoView(
                        imageProvider: NetworkImage(url),
                    )
                ),
                onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```